# Is there a word for the use of a nationality to change the meaning of a noun?

Tags: single-word-requests

In phrases such as *Russian Roulette*, *Dutch Courage* and *French Letter* the nationality changes the meaning of the noun. Is there a word for this?

Comment: I've only ever heard these called idioms of nationality (or ethnicity). I'm not sure there is a specific term for this, but I would be interested to hear the answer. A caveat: I expect many of these may be offensive to the nationalities mentioned. It is not a big step from "Dutch courage" to "a Chinaman's chance" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinaman's_chance) or "Indian giver" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_giver). And the group degraded changes depending on the nationality of the speaker. For example, the German for banjo used to be *Negergitarre* (literally, "nigger guitar").

Comment: Indeed, Dutch Courage was originally a back-handed insult. It was originally coined at a time when Britain and the Netherlands were at war, and was meant to insinuate that the Dutch were only courageous when drunk.  It would be a thin-skinned Dutch person that would be offended by it nowadays though surely?

Comment: I am Dutch, and I don't think you could find a single person here who'd be offended. The same applies to "going Dutch", mostly because, well, that is actually quite a normal thing to do here. No offense, but we might call this sort of sensitivity "American thin skin" or something like that <ducks>.

Comment: Sometimes the feeling is mutual - the phrase "to take French leave" (meaning to take holiday from work without permission) is expressed in French as "filer à l'anglaise"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I can't locate a technical term for these, the terms *nationality idioms* and *ethnicity idioms* appear to be commonly used.

Comment: thank you. I am surprised there is no word for it, especially in the light of this... http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8543/what-is-it-called-when-an-interjection-is-inserted-inside-another-word