# Is there a term for "*cough*<something>*cough*"?

Tags: linguistics

What I mean is the act of "coughing" something that you don't actually want to (or rather dare) say outright.  So instead of writing, say, "Miss Parker", you'd write "*cough*Ms Parker*cough*" or fake a cough that sounds very much like "Miss Parker".

Written and spoken differ in that of course, when written is absolutely clear what that "coughed" term is, while when spoken it's "hidden" in the cough (which the written form tries to express).

Never heard it in conversation, only heard it in movies or read it in books, though my contact to actual English native-speakers is (sadly) limited.

Is there a linguistic/rhetorical term for that?

Comment: Not sure what you'd called it, but it does get used frequently in conversations among friends, especially youngsters.

Comment: @Brian thanks!  This was my second question, but I wanted to keep it to one only.  Thanks for answering it anyway ;-)

Comment: I guess in the spirit of [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8543/what-is-it-called-when-an-interjection-is-inserted-inside-another-word) question, you could call it an 'outerjection' or an 'outfixation' :) (Did that question inspire this one?)

Comment: @Benjol if it was, then it wasn't a conscious inspiration. :)

Comment: TV Tropes just calls it http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CoughSnarkCough.

Comment: Are you looking for a rhetoric term for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I haven't focus grouped it, "cough" as a verb of saying sounds OK to me and expresses the desired meaning. As in

> "I crashed your truck," the porter coughed.

or

> She coughed the words "thirty seconds," in response to her mother's demand to know how long she had spent considering her options.

Comment: Accepted, even though those examples are not totally what I have in mind.  But "cough" as a verb works nicely.

Answer (score 8):

The best I can come up with is the idiom to say something *under your breath*.

Closely related words which may cover this are to *mutter*, *mumble* or *mussitate*.

Answer (score 6):

It's a parenthetical comment, demarcated with a pair of "ahem," rather than the usual parenthesis (as this comment is), or by commas, as this one is, marking the parenthetical comment.

The use of "cough" as opposed to "ahem" seems to be fairly modern, but ahem is an onomatopoeia (a word that replicates or nearly replicates a sound that it represents) for throat clearing.

Similar parenthetical onmatopoeia include "sigh," "whimper," "moan," "groan," and "ah." Frank Herbert used "Ahhmmm" for the character of Count Hasimir Fenring in his dune novels, occasionally as parenthetical markers.

Answer (score 4):

This can be called a *[hem](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=ahem)*, and is often written as *[ahem](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ahem)*.

I'm not sure this covers the case where the speaker actually coughs over a word.

Comment: I don't think ahem covers coughing. The two links you provided only refer to throat-clearing.

Comment: @Mr Please check the second link again.

Comment: Speaking of throat-clears, I suppose it would not be off-topic to make mention of the following satirical article: http://specgram.com/CLXVIII.1/04.caws-elwitt.review.html