# Term for words such as "un-f**king-believable" or "a-whole-nother"

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is it called when an interjection is inserted inside another word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8543/what-is-it-called-when-an-interjection-is-inserted-inside-another-word)

Is there a term used to describe words such as *un-fucking-believable* or *a-whole-nother*? These words have other words inserted inside of the original word, creating a sort of compound word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tmesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmesis) is also used to describe this construction, [when a lexical word is inserted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmesis#Other_tmesis_in_English) as an intensifier. And yes, [expletives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive_infixation) are very often used as intensifiers in these cases.

It's also originally found in words like *whatsoever/what-so-ever*, *howsoever/how-so-ever*, etc., which are now words in their own right.

There are [rules about where we stick the intensifier](http://works.bepress.com/john_j_mccarthy/11/), based on [prosody](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosody_%28linguistics%29) in English. We don't find **unbe-fucking-lievable* but we do find *abso-fucking-lutely*. An interesting thing about *a-whole-nother* is where another is divided; it's not **an-whole-other* as one would expect.

Comment: I know I, and other people I know, have used "unbe-fucking-lievable". It's even used differently semantically from "un-fucking-believable". The latter is pronounced as three distinct words, like in a shocked manner ("Un. Fucking. Believable."); the former is a single word and is used more often in anger ("That's some unbefuckinglievable bullshit!").

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's called an *infix*. Its use in English is confined to such examples, but it is a normal feature of some other languages.

Comment: Abso-bleedin'-lutely.