# Meaning of the word "congratufukinlation"

Tags: meaning, offensive-language

What does congratu-fukin-lations mean?

Comment: Added the offensive-language tag. I hope that isn't the source of the downvoting and the close vote, as people who don't want to see such questions can just filter out that tag.

Comment: Too localized.  [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22congratufukinlation%22) turns up exactly three other instances of the word: once on a forum, once in a chatroom, and once in a youtube comment.

Comment: @Danielδ - Perhaps just because of the weird spelling used above? I've heard it in the wild on occasion.

Comment: I suppose it could be viewed as a question on expletive infixation in general.

Comment: If you knew there was expletive language in the word, then surely you could work out what the word itself must mean.

Comment: @Urbycoz - He didn't add that tag. I did. Someone else inserted the helpful hyphens. I suspect the OQ really had no idea, and as Daniel pointed out, an internet search wouldn't have been all that helpful.

Comment: It's not Too Localised - it's a duplicate of [What is it called when an interjection is inserted inside another word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8543/)

Answer (score 9):

This is [expletive infixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive_infixation): where an expletive is added into the middle of a word to give extra impact (or sometimes sarcasm).

See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8543/what-is-it-called-when-an-interjection-is-inserted-inside-another-word) for more discussion.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a typical word. It's "congratulations" with "fukin" (a slight misspelling of an expletive) inserted in the middle.

How that expletive changes the meaning depends a bit on context. In general the intention would be to *intensify the sentiment*. However, the sentiment could actually be *sarcastic*. In that case it would be something along the lines of "I guess that's great for *you* but it doesn't do anything for *me*".