# Split-word phenomenon

Tags: single-word-requests, figures-of-speech

There's a phenomenon I've encountered occasionally of splitting a word for emphasis:

> Do I want to get a kebab? Abso-bloomin'-lutely!

Being "absolutely" given the enhancement of the insertion of "bloomin'" to convey enthusiasm for the proposed course. Occasionally "bloomin'" would find itself ousted in favour of "bloody" or something of a more Anglo-Saxon favour.

Then today this (fictionalised for ease) occurred on the radio:

> Yes, It's as if I was here in a past life. I feel like I walked this way *in different carnations*.

This seems more of an insertion of "different" as it fit with the flow of the sentence more than for any emphasis.

**Question:**

Is there a name for this class of phenomenon, are the two instances described together or distinguished in some way?

Comment: I accidentally searched for duplicates on ELL instead of ELU. Not finding a suitable candidate, I posted an answer here. But checking again I see it obviously it ***is*** a duplicate (OP's ***in**carnation* example above is effectively meaningless).

Comment: Thanks for answering and pointing it out. I searched for a dupe here but obviously didn't specify the correct terms to unearth [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8543/61803). @FumbleFingers Closing as duplicate.

Comment: I've only just noticed your ***(fictionalised for ease)*** disclaimer before the second example. I'm guessing either you misheard something or you've mistranscribed it. I suppose it's feasible a native speaker might discard the first syllable from ***in**carnation* by way of "wordplay" in some unusual context, but I doubt there's anything useful for you to learn in that area.

Comment: I'm in the position that I can check as i-Player should have it. I'll not report back unless there's something remarkable. @FumbleFingers

Comment: I can perhaps imagine ***in different carnations*** being used facetiously. Compare with *That's **a** whole **'nother** ball game* - which is syntactic garbage (it should be ***other*** or ***different***, not a contraction of ***another***). But that type of wordplay is probably best avoided by most learners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called...

> [**Expletive infixation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive_infixation) (Wikipedia)
> a process by which an expletive or profanity is inserted into a word, usually for intensification.

The OP's cited usage *in different carnations* doesn't really have a name. It's just a "mistake". Or maybe ***[malapropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism)*** (the speaker/writer should have used *in different **in**carnations*).