# Meaning of "She'll get you in Dutch"?

Tags: meaning

In the lyrics of the Coasters' 1959 song "Poison Ivy" there are the lines

> She comes on like a rose but everybody knows
>   She'll get you in Dutch
>   Now you can look but you better not touch

The song  is apparently about  a woman who transmits  a venereal disease and my question is:

> What does "she'll get you in Dutch" mean?

Comment: Strongly related: [A question about Dutch words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110497/is-dutch-wife-one-of-those-dutch-words)

Comment: _In trouble_ - general reference http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+Dutch

Comment: Ah, thanks mplungjan. Is that idiom still in use in the USA?

Comment: I see that jwpat7 has answered the question in my comment: the idiom is dated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A glance at wiktionary's entry for  *[in Dutch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_Dutch)* shows:

> (idiomatic, dated) In trouble or in disfavor [eg] He got in dutch with City Manager George Schrader when he made some ill-chosen remarks.

Also see the previously-mentioned questions, [Is “Dutch wife” one of those “Dutch words”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/110497).