# Does "Japanese tourist" have any meaning other than a tourist from Japan?

Tags: phrases, offensive-language

I was under the impression that "Japanese tourist" had a meaning more than just a tourist who happens to be from Japan.

For example, TV Tropes has an entry on [Japanese Tourist](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/JapaneseTourist), and [French fashion boss offends Chinese over elitist Paris hotel](http://www.english.rfi.fr/visiting-france/20121005-french-fashion-boss-offends-chinese-over-elitist-paris-hotel) describes the reaction when "Chinese tourist" (which I assume is the same as "Japanese tourist", but updated for the new century) was interpreted literally (tourists from China) rather than figuratively (mass tourism).

However, others seem to be skeptical of this. One person commented

> I don't think there is a special term - just as in English, "Japanese
>   tourist"/"Chinese tourist" could be a neutral descriptor in many
>   contexts. It's more a stereotype than a figurative meaning.

Does "Japanese tourist" have any meaning other than merely a tourist from Japan, like "Polish plumber" means something other than just a plumber from Poland?

Comment: The term brings to mind packaged tours and compulsive picture taking to me and I would say Japanese rather than Chinese. No offense meant to either of course, I know these are just stereotypes.

Comment: In the US, especially in California, "Japanese tourist" is a stereotype for someone traveling in a tightly-managed tour group -- off the bus, tour the museum for 15 minutes, back on the bus and off to the next stop.  (Though perhaps the stereotype is not as strong as it was 20-30 years ago.)

Comment: I think he's after connotations rather than strict meaning, as the connotation of "Polish plumber" is someone who takes British jobs, and no one cares that the individual before you might actually be Lithuanian. So yes, I think we are meant to think, not merely of packaged tours, everyone has those, but of couriers with _flags_ leading groups wearing _colour-coded_ hats and jumpsuits (they do this at home as well), and not merely compulsive picture-taking, but ditto with selfie-sticks.

Comment: @HotLicks: Your bus-museum-bus thing I associate just as much with, guess what, _Americans_ as with the Japanese. We Europeans satirise them with the line, "If this is Tuesday, it must be Belgium". Same reasons: it is expensive to get to Europe, and everyone at home will ask you why you didn't catch XYZ. I was once going to take a Singaporean around Switzerland, but pulled the plug when she insisted on a side-trip from the peace and air of the high Alps to summertime Venice, lest she lose peer kudos.

Comment: @DavidPugh - I was about add that the same image probably applied to US tourists in Europe.  However, my understanding is that the Japanese-run tours of 20-30 years ago took this to the extreme.  (I mean *literally* 15 minutes in the museum -- no American tourist would have tolerated this.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of these kinds of nationality/noun things ARE intended as pejoratives.  Most seem not to be, however.

I think that "Japanese tourist" is a slight slam.  I believe it has to do with going places dressed fairly wildly for the venue, carrying two or three cameras and taking shots of everything.  Like I did last week at my granddaughter's wedding.

Didn't they used to call American tourists "the ugly American"?  Sure they did.

I am originally from California, and am reminded of something called a "Chinese Fire Drill" or sometimes "Mexican Fire Drill", where a car full of young people stop at a red traffic light and everyone exits the car and re-enters it using a different door from the one they exited at, frequently including the driver.  This is amusing to watch, and probably a scream to do.  It works only on 4-door cars, though.  It is possibly offensive to Chinese or Mexican people, and surely not PC, but I doubt it is intended as a great insult.  Best to give it a different name, I am sure.

Then there's a Dutch Date, which is where a man and woman go on a "date" and instead of the man paying for everything, they each pay half, or for their own expenses.  Dutch refers to Holland, or the Netherlands, of course.  This has to do with thriftiness, I suppose and I don't know if any Nederlanders would be offended by the term.

And how about someone who is counted thrifty being referred to as being Scotch?  Which is a misnomer, since it should be Scot, or Scottish.  The legend being that Scots are very thrifty.  My own Mom used to say of my father spending money on something she didn't approve of, "That just gets my Scotch blood all riled up!"  Any Scots offended by this?

And let's not forget "That's White of you!"  This is an oldy; it is meant to imply approval for some favor.  A variant when supplicating another for a favor was "Oh, be a White guy and [do this thing for me]."  The last time I heard it was in 1968 in high school in Toronto, Canada when a friend and fraternity brother of mine used the former phrase to commend another one our fraternity brothers for something he had done.

Ironically, the particular frat brother he was addressing was Colored -- you know, the old Apartheid term for someone who was part white and part black -- and this is appropo to mention because he was in fact from South Africa.  Now THAT was very offensive, something the frat bro in question didn't seem to realize, but I did, and I cringed like a sonuvagun.  The frat bro on the receiving end of this was, fortunately, a very laid-back and patient man, so there was no contretemps, but I was horribly embarrassed.

The first written records of an outbreak of syphilis in Europe occurred in 1494 or 1495 in Naples, Italy, during a French invasion. Due to its being spread by returning French troops, it was initially known as the "French disease."  Ouch!

I can't think of anything else at the moment.  Fortunately.

Comment: "Dutch" because the ethnic English discriminated against the Dutch in the state of New York after the American Revolution and saw them as "cheap". The Dutch ethnics were pushed further upstate by the English. Hence the Dutch town names in upstate and mid-state NY.

Comment: Believe me, _American_ is indeed used as all sorts of different insults and slurs outside the US. Depending on the country it can mean any or all of _stupid_, _unsophisticated_, _uneducated_, _fat_ or _loud_. :)

Comment: Related questions about "Dutch date" and the like: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8511/1420 and http://english.stackexchange.com/q/110497/1420

Comment: @BlessedGeek and more generally, England and Holland were strong rivals on the seas and had several wars, and some more objectionable terms such as *Dutch wife* or *Dutch widow* for a prostitute came from that time. I'm not convinced that "Japanese tourist" is comparable, but simply applies to the fact that in the 80s and 90s groups of tourists from Japan who acted in ways that seemed strange to the locals (part of which being cultural differences, and part from the logistics of group travel) were a new phenomenon.

Comment: @terdon, I traveled a bit in the 70's and 80's and actually lived in England and Germany, and visited France for a couple of weeks (on a motorcycle).  Maybe things have changed?  But I never encountered much in the way of insult or slurs for being American.  Perhaps I was smart, sophisticated, educated, skinny and quiet?  Hmmm.  Quiet and skinny (at the time) maybe, not so much the rest.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist I was _born_ in 1980 and have lived my life in Europe, specifically in Greece, the UK, Spain and France and in each of those countries you can encounter American used as an insult. This does not mean you will necessarily encounter that many people whose prejudices survive actually meeting an example of the species. I have no idea if that was the case before but I know that it definitely increased (understandably enough) during the Bush years. Anyway, I'm sure you're still skinny ;)

Comment: @terdon, I am skinny only in my dreams!  You make a good point about actually meeting someone of a given group.  There's a bit of anti-French sentiment over here, with the French reckoned as arrogant, effete, and full of unjustifiable pride. But I found the French to be friendly, helpful and happy folk. And about the George W Bush thing, I do not necessarily understand this. I liked him, both as a person (whom I'd never met) and as a President.  He was down-to-earth, not full of himself, and no idiot, despite liberal propaganda. I voted for him both times, as did quite a few other Americans.

Comment: This is not the place to get into a political discussion but suffice it to say that your views are not shared by many in Europe and that US foreign policy with him at the helm was presumptuous, overbearing, and undiplomatic which can cause friction abroad.

Comment: I know, @terdon, but **since you brought it up in the first place**, I felt compelled to defend someone whom I supported and thought was being unjustly criticized.  If I were to make the unnecessary comment here that Hollande of France is a *presumptuous, overbearing, and undiplomatic* leader, would I not expect a supporter of his to just let it pass without defending him?  One should not assume that everyone in the world shares one's political opinion, and state it as if it were the default position -- with words like "understandably enough" -- at least not in this venue.

Comment: Fair enough on all counts (though I'd love to talk about this more with someone as articulate as yourself). All I meant to say was that the way that European countries were treated by the Bush administration caused a lot of resentment here (I was name-calling the foreign policy, not the man himself and whether or not it was meant to be, it was certainly _perceived_ as all the adjectives I used). At any rate, the fact remains that anti-american sentiment and the resultant slurs went up dramatically during the Bush years. Whether that was due to a misconception or not is besides the point.

Comment: I understand your points as well, @terdon. As it happens, I don't think US foreign policy under *any* recent President has been all that well carried out. The word "muddled" about sums it up.  Ah, well.  Thanks for an interesting discussion! :-)

Comment: There are lots more. Dutch Courage, Dutch Uncle and being in Dutch are derogatory, though Dutch Auction is neutral. We have more nasty terms for the Dutch than the French, probably from the wars under Charles II, which we lost.  In Parisian sex ads, BDS&M is called "_disciplin anglais_". Here is something else strange for you, Cyberherbalist. Cameroonians can use "white" in precisely your frat sense, which I associate with c. 1900 literature ("I say, Smithers, old boy, that's very white of you.") The first time I heard that it made me queasy.

Comment: Wow, @DavidPugh!  That's quite an observation -- I would have gone queasy, too!